# Remove [localhost]

Tags: discussion, tags

I just recently answered a question that was tagged with [localhost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localhost). It's the only question that uses this tag but the tag doesn’t add anything to the question.

The tag seems to have been created without any *usage guidance* or *wiki description* so it’s not clear what the creator intended the tag for. While there’s still only one question using this tag (and no followers), I thought it would be good to either

1. get rid of it or
2. write appropriate usage guidance and tag wiki for it

I’d lean towards the first option but only because I can’t personally think of a good use for the tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't see much of a use case for it. You can just remove it from the post; [unused tags are deleted daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/145982), so it'll get removed automatically